# How to extract data from Facebook canvas graph?

Tags: python, selenium, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a program in Phyton that automates writing reports. 
I need to extract data from Facebook graphs: Organic Likes and Paid Likes.

I've tried using Selenium Xpath, but the inspector tool cannot find the element i'm looking for, it changes as I move the mouse around.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/12az2.jpg

I also tried using Facebook Graph Api, but failed to find words that could help me extract the data i'm looking for.

```
This code is just my way to go from login to desired part of Facebook.
```

```
#----------Facebook ----------

    driver.get("http:facebook.com/")
    driver.maximize_window()

    pyautogui.click(414, 750);
    pyautogui.dragTo(151, 750);
    pyautogui.click(151, 750);


#Login

    time.sleep(1.5)
    pyautogui.click(811, 211); pyautogui.typewrite('login')
    time.sleep(.5)
    pyautogui.click(975, 213); pyautogui.typewrite('password')
    pyautogui.click(1135, 213);

    time sleep(20) #---write security google token
    time.sleep(10) #--------loading of home site
    pyautogui.click(235, 370);
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(839, 179);
    time.sleep(1.5)
    pyautogui.click(839, 225);

#navigation
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(229, 472);
    time.sleep(15) # user picks date

#Add likes
    pyautogui.click(x, y);
    pyautogui.dragTo(691, 361);
```

I want to be able to copy and paste individual numbers from the graph.
I currently unable to due to inability to locate the number because the moment i click or move away the mouse the number dissapears.

Comment: canvas is a bitmap, but it's possibly they are overlaying DOM items you could access.  If the item you need is indeed inside the canvas, you will have trouble doing anything other than taking a screenshot of it.  (though there are some open-source object recognition libraries out there.)  By the way, you may want to use Selenium for your login stuff.  Should be a bit more robust to work with the DOM.

Comment: ...though come to think of it, the canvas should be drawn using javascript so you may be able to get the data you need by mocking certain calls and getting the callback data.  The API seems like it should have all the data you need, though.  Why not use that server-side?  (the API shows "paid likes"? lol...)

Comment: Not sure what data exactly you’re after here, but have you checked whether it’s available via the Insights API endpoint? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/insights

Comment: @pcalkins _“(the API shows "paid likes"? lol...) ”_ - haha, no, that’s not as shady as it sounds; it just means the like was the result of someone having been shown a paid ad or something like that.

Comment: @04FS I'm looking for a number represented by singleton on the graph (as shown on a image above)